Sending Ethernet Frame Without any local network (Scappy)
I am using two computers, one in linux with wireshark and monitor mode activated to sniff all nearby requests, and one with windows that uses scappy to send ethernet frames.
Is it possible to send ethernet frames without being connected to any kind of local network, and is it possible for wireshark to detect them ?
I ran this code for scapy
my_frame=Ether()
p=srp(my_frame, iface="Wi-Fi")

this is what i get from scapy
Begin emission:
WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast.
Finished sending 1 packets.
*
Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
'my_mac_adress' > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff (0x9000) ==> 'my_mac_adress' > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff (0x9000)

